# Re-deploying a Jboss Web Project

Tags: jboss

I have created a Java EE Web Application in Jboss Developer Studio and deployed it (**Run as** => **Run on Server**). Then, I undeployed my project by Management CLI of Jboss eap server.
Later, when trying to deploy the project again (**Run as** => **Run on Server**), it failed with the following:

> BWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 - /myproject
>
> JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000067: Status report
>
> JBWEB000068: message /myproject
>
> JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not
>   available.
>
> JBoss Web/7.4.8.Final-redhat-4

How do I deploy a project after undeploying?